# Applying rowcolor to tabularx in spreadtab causes "TeX capacity exceeded" error

Tags: tabularx, colortbl, scrlttr2, spreadtab

Trying to apply `\rowcolor{gray}` to a specific row of a `tabularx` table whose values are calculated from `spreadtab` causes the famous error

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].

Might it have something to do with some column size? I cannot make a sense of it. Please find MWE below, and note the `scrlttr2` documentclass. Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{siunitx}   % align by decimal point
\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-family=true}
\sisetup{locale = DE}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{spreadtab} % for table calculation
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace} % for fantom space
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
Hi
\newcommand\Rate{50}
\medskip\par\noindent
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rlcS[table-format=5.2,round-integer-to-decimal,round-mode = places]}}%<{\euro}
  \toprule
  %A & B                                        & C                  & D
  @  & @\textbf{Item}                           & @\textbf{Amount}   & @\textbf{Total (\euro)}       \\ \midrule  
  @1 & @some relatively long text for no reason & 3                  & c2*\Rate                      \\  
  @2 & @Bar                                     & 3                  & c3*\Rate                      \\          
  @3 & @Baz                                     & 1                  & c4*\Rate                      \\  \midrule 
     & \hspace{0pt plus 1filll} @Total:         & sum(c2:c4)         &                               \\  
     & \hspace{0pt plus 1filll} @Rate:          & @\Rate\xspace\euro &                               \\  \midrule
     & \hspace{0pt plus 1filll} @Sum netto:     &                    & sum(d2:d4)                    \\  
     & \hspace{0pt plus 1filll} @Tax 19\%:      &                    & 0.19*[0,-1]                   \\
%\rowcolor{gray}  % <-------------------
     & \hspace{0pt plus 1filll} @Total:         &                    & :={[0,-1]+[0,-2]}\xspace\euro \\  
  \bottomrule 
\end{spreadtab}
\medskip\par

\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

smaller example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular*}{\textwidth}{rlcc}}
  @1 & @text for no reason & @z   & @h       \\  
\rowcolor{red}
a&b&c&d
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a smaller example giving the same error, as it will be easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle. I keep it not-so-minimal since I was not sure if any of the packages were the culprit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe `a & b & c & d` should be `@a & @b & @c & @d` in your smaller example? It gives error due to the missing `@`'s, and `\rowcolor{red}` doesn't gives error if I add `@`'s there.

Comment: @Pouya it is easy for you to check whether packages are involved before posting the example by doing as I did and just remove them while preserving the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

---

### Solution for `siunitx` version 3

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{xspace} % for fantom space
\usepackage{spreadtab} % for table calculation
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-family=true}
\sisetup{locale = DE}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{}
Hi
\newcommand\Rate{50}
\medskip\par\noindent
\begin{spreadtab}{{tblr}{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec={rlcX[l,si={table-format=5.2,round-integer-to-decimal,round-mode = places,table-number-alignment=left}]},
  hline{1,10} = {0.08em},    % toprule and bottomrule
  hline{2,5,7} = {0.05em},   % midrule
  cell{5-9}{2} = {r},        % right alignment
  row{1} = {font=\rmfamily\bfseries}, % row font
  row{9} = {gray8},          % row color
}}
  @  & @Item                                    & @Amount            & @{{{Total (\euro)}}}          \\ 
  @1 & @some relatively long text for no reason & 3                  & c2*\Rate                      \\  
  @2 & @Bar                                     & 3                  & c3*\Rate                      \\          
  @3 & @Baz                                     & 1                  & c4*\Rate                      \\ 
     & @Total:                                  & sum(c2:c4)         &                               \\  
     & @Rate:                                   & @\Rate\xspace\euro &                               \\
     & @Sum netto:                              &                    & sum(d2:d4)                    \\  
     & @Tax 19\%:                               &                    & 0.19*[0,-1]                   \\
     & @Total:                                  &                    & :={[0,-1]+[0,-2]}\xspace\euro \\  
\end{spreadtab}
\medskip\par
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Solution for `siunitx` version 2

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{xspace} % for fantom space
\usepackage{spreadtab} % for table calculation
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-family=true}
\sisetup{locale = DE}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{}
Hi
\newcommand\Rate{50}
\medskip\par\noindent
\begin{spreadtab}{{tblr}{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec={rlcQ[r,si={table-format=5.2,round-integer-to-decimal,round-mode = places,table-number-alignment=left}]@{}X},
  hline{1,10} = {0.08em},    % toprule and bottomrule
  hline{2,5,7} = {0.05em},   % midrule
  cell{5-9}{2} = {r},        % right alignment
  row{1} = {font=\rmfamily\bfseries}, % row font
  row{9} = {gray8},          % row color
}}
  @  & @Item                                    & @Amount            & @{{{Total}}} & @\,(\euro)         \\
  @1 & @some relatively long text for no reason & 3                  & c2*\Rate                      \\
  @2 & @Bar                                     & 3                  & c3*\Rate                      \\
  @3 & @Baz                                     & 1                  & c4*\Rate                      \\
     & @Total:                                  & sum(c2:c4)         & @{{{}}}                              \\
     & @Rate:                                   & @\Rate\xspace\euro & @{{{}}}                              \\
     & @Sum netto:                              &                    & sum(d2:d4)                    \\
     & @Tax 19\%:                               &                    & 0.19*[0,-1]                   \\
     & @Total:                                  &                    & :={[0,-1]+[0,-2]} & @\xspace\euro \\
\end{spreadtab}
\medskip\par
\closing{Bye}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately after installing this and ninecolors package your MWE fails with `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 38.` and `Emergency stop.`. Line 38 is the `\end{spreadtab}`.

Comment: Strange. Have you updated your TeX distribution to the latest?

Comment: I'm on TeX Live 2020, not 2021 and unfortunately cannot update to 2021 right now. Any workarounds?

Comment: Download `tabularray.sty` and `ninecolors.sty` from CTAN, and put them in the folder of your tex file.

Comment: Well, this is how I compiled your code and failed (as mentioned in my first comment). Though I got it from your github.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a solution for `siunitx` version 2 in `texlive` 2020.