# How to handle calculations in tabularx?

Tags: environments, tabularx, calculations

I try to create an invoice letter with automatic calculations of the invoice sum. Using `tabular` everything works.
With `tabularx` the counters do work correctly but the calculations do not. I understand that is because `tabularx` needs to run the code for the table multiple times to estimate the widths and set the correct `X` column width.

Why does this just effect the calculations but not the counters?

I tried solving the problem by comparing the item number counter `numberedlistcounter` (displayed correctly) with a calculation counter `sumcounter` but it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

%===================================
% automatic counter for lists

\newcommand{\startnumberedlist}{\newcounter{numberedlistcounter}}
\newcommand{\numberedlistitem}{\stepcounter{numberedlistcounter}\thenumberedlistcounter}
\newcommand{\numberitemsinlist}{\thenumberedlistcounter\xspace}

%===================================
% display numbers according DIN 5008 (normal numbers with space as thousand separator and money amounts with . as separator)

\RequirePackage[detect-all, separate-uncertainty, group-minimum-digits = 4]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE, group-separator = {\,}, input-decimal-markers={,.}, output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\newcommand{\euro}[1]{
    \num[round-precision = 2, round-mode = places, group-separator = {.}, locale=DE]{#1}\,€
}

%===================================
% invoice environment (needs \euro and siunitx)

\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{calculator}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\resetinvoicesum}{\ADD{0}{0}{\invoicesum}
    \newcounter{sumcounter}}
\newcommand{\addtoinvoicesum}[1]{
    \ifx\numberedlistcounter=\sumcounter 
    \else 
        \ADD{\invoicesum}{#1}{\invoicesum}\GLOBALCOPY{\invoicesum}{\invoicesum}
        %\thesumcounter
        \stepcounter{sumcounter}
    \fi
}

\newenvironment{invoice}[1][]
{\startnumberedlist\resetinvoicesum\par\noindent
    \centering\tabularx{\textwidth}{cXS[table-format=5.1]rr}%
    \toprule[0.7pt]\textbf{Pos.} & \textbf{Beschreibung} & \textbf{Anzahl} & \textbf{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Gesamtpreis} \\ \toprule[0.7pt]}
{\midrule[0.7pt] 
    &&& \textbf{Rechnungsbetrag} & \textbf{\euro{\invoicesum}} \\ \cmidrule[0.7pt]{4-5} \endtabularx}

% invoiceitem, #1: description, #2: count, #3: price per item
\newcommand{\invoiceitem}[3]{\numberedlistitem & #1 & #2 &  \euro{#3} & 
    \MULTIPLY{#2}{#3}{\tempsum} \addtoinvoicesum{\tempsum} \euro{\tempsum}\\} % price calculation and sum up all prices

%===================================

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{}
        
        \begin{invoice}
            \invoiceitem{Arbeitszeit in h}{80}{15}
            \invoiceitem{Schrauben}{2134}{0,1}
            \invoiceitem{Strommenge in kWh}{303,5}{0,3175}
            \invoiceitem{Werkzeug}{2}{1123,1}
        \end{invoice}
        
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: Also for whatever reason the last cell with the sum is not aligned to the right as all the other cells above. Why is that?

Comment: tabularx takes special care to reset all LaTeX counters. I wouldn't do the calculations inside the tabularx, either use a tabular and calculate the column width yourself, or calculate your invoice values before the table and store them in some command and then build the table.

Comment: The package `spreadtab` is designed specifically to calculate values using other cells. It essentially turns  `tabularx` environment into a spreadsheet.

Comment: @alchemist: I already looked into that. I can't get `spreadtab` to work in environments. Even with using `\spreadtab` and `\enspreadtab`...

Comment: See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604087/ can help you.

Comment: I see. Just a question though: you use `\Requirepackage{}` instead of `\usepackage{}` several times. Are you planning to create a custom class file to create your invoices?

Comment: @alchemist: From my understanding `RequirePackage{}` and `\usepackage{}` work the same with the difference that `\RequirePackage{}` does not throw an error when a package is included twice. Apart from that, I really want to use the code in a class or an .lco file to be available for use in different documents.