# How to manually create X width of tabularx?

Tags: tables, environments

I want to create a automatically calculating invoice environment.

The table fits to the page perfectly (of course) with `tabularx`. However, the calculation goes wrong since LaTeX creates the table multiple times to find out the width of the `X` column.

The calculations work great with `tabular` but then the table is fully fitting on the page depending on the font settings.

So I tried to manually calculate the width of the one variable column but it does not really work smoothly. Is there a better way to solve this?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\RequirePackage{xspace}

% =====================================
% correct number displaying

\usepackage[mode=text, reset-text-series = false, separate-uncertainty, group-digits=integer, group-minimum-digits = 4]{siunitx}

\sisetup{group-separator = {\,}, input-decimal-markers={,.}, output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\newcommand{\EURsimple}[1]{
    \sisetup{minimum-decimal-digits=2, group-separator = {.}, output-decimal-marker = {,}}
    #1
    \sisetup{minimum-decimal-digits=0, group-separator = {\,}, output-decimal-marker = {,}} 
}

\newcommand{\EUR}[1]{
    \num[minimum-decimal-digits=2, group-separator = {.}, output-decimal-marker = {,}]{#1}\,€
}

% =====================================
% automatic item numbering

\newcommand{\startnumberedlist}{\newcounter{numberedlistcounter}}
\newcommand{\numberedlistitem}{\stepcounter{numberedlistcounter}\thenumberedlistcounter}

% =====================================
% calculation

\RequirePackage{calculator}

\newcommand{\resetinvoicesum}{\ADD{0}{0}{\invoicesum}}
\newcommand{\addtoinvoicesum}[1]{\ADD{\invoicesum}{#1}{\invoicesum}\GLOBALCOPY{\invoicesum}{\invoicesum}}

% =====================================
% trying to calculate the needed width of the variable width column

\newlength{\invoicedescwidth}
\setlength{\invoicedescwidth}{\textwidth}

\newlength{\invoicerestwidth}
\settowidth{\invoicerestwidth}{\textbf{Pos. Anzahl Rechnungsbetrag Gesamtpreis}}

\addtolength{\invoicedescwidth}{-\invoicerestwidth}
\addtolength{\invoicedescwidth}{-15ex}  % <= this is not variable enough for different fonts. 

% =====================================
% invoice environment

\RequirePackage{booktabs}

\newenvironment{invoice}[1][]{\startnumberedlist\resetinvoicesum\par\noindent
    \centering\begin{tabular}{rp{\invoicedescwidth}S[table-format=5.1]S[table-format=5.4]r}%
        \toprule[0.7pt]\textbf{Pos.} & \textbf{Beschreibung} & \textbf{Anzahl} & \textbf{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Gesamtpreis} \\ \toprule[0.7pt]}
    {\midrule[0.7pt] 
        &&& \textbf{Rechnungsbetrag} & \textbf{\EUR{\invoicesum}} \\ \cmidrule[0.7pt]{4-5} \end{tabular}%
}

% invoiceitem, #1: description, #2: count, #3: price per item
\newcommand{\invoiceitem}[3]{
    \numberedlistitem & #1 & #2 & \EURsimple{#3} & \MULTIPLY{#2}{#3}{\tempsum} \ROUND[2]{\tempsum}{\tempsum} \addtoinvoicesum{\tempsum} \EUR{\tempsum}\\} % price calculation and sum up all prices


\usepackage{Blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{recipient}
        \opening{Hello}
        
        \Blindtext[1]
        
        \begin{invoice}
            \invoiceitem{Arbeitszeit in h}{800}{15}
            \invoiceitem{Schrauben}{2134}{0.1}
            \invoiceitem{Strommenge in kWh}{303.5}{0.3175}
            \invoiceitem{Position C}{2}{1123.1}
        \end{invoice}
        
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: I also tried `tabularray` but that does not seem to work with `S` columns of `siunitx` to arrange the numbers correctly at the decimal point.

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604087/ applying-rowcolor-to-tabularx-in-spreadtab-causes-tex-capacity-exceeded-error can help you.

Comment: Longtable also stores the column widths in the aux file.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-obtain-width-of-longtable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the calculations in

```
\newlength{\invoicedescwidth}
\setlength{\invoicedescwidth}{\textwidth}
\newlength{\invoicerestwidth}
\settowidth{\invoicerestwidth}{\textbf{Pos. Anzahl Rechnungsbetrag Gesamtpreis}} 
\addtolength{\invoicedescwidth}{-\invoicerestwidth}
\addtolength{\invoicedescwidth}{-15ex}  % <= this is not variable enough for different fonts.
```

are suspect. E.g., why aren't you casting the text portion in `\textsf`? Why are there spaces in the `Pos. Anzahl Rechnungsbetrag Gesamtpreis` string? Where does `15ex` come from? I suggest you replace the code block with

```
% manual calculation of required column width
\newlength\mylenA
\newlength\invoicedescwidth
\settowidth\mylenA{% some text, some numbers, no spaces, all \textsf
  \textsf{\textbf{Pos.Gesamtpreis}22\,124,511.123,3175}}
\setlength\invoicedescwidth{%
  \dimexpr\textwidth-\mylenA-8\tabcolsep\relax}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% correct number displaying
\usepackage[mode=text, 
            reset-text-series = false, 
            separate-uncertainty, 
            group-digits=integer, 
            group-minimum-digits = 4
           ]{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {\,}, 
         input-decimal-markers={,.}, 
         output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\newcommand{\EURsimple}[1]{
    \sisetup{minimum-decimal-digits=2, 
             group-separator = {.}, 
             output-decimal-marker = {,}}
    #1
    \sisetup{minimum-decimal-digits=0, 
             group-separator = {\,}, 
             output-decimal-marker = {,}} 
}

\newcommand{\EUR}[1]{
    \num[minimum-decimal-digits=2, 
         group-separator = {.}, 
         output-decimal-marker = {,}]{#1}\,€%
}

% automatic item numbering
\newcounter{numberedlistcounter}
\newcommand{\resetnumberedlist}{%
   \setcounter{numberedlistcounter}{0}}
\newcommand{\numberedlistitem}{%
   \stepcounter{numberedlistcounter}%
   \thenumberedlistcounter}
   
% manual calculation of required column width
\newlength\mylenA
\newlength\invoicedescwidth
\settowidth\mylenA{%   
  \textsf{\textbf{Pos.Gesamtpreis}22\,124,511.123,3175}}
\setlength\invoicedescwidth{%
  \dimexpr\textwidth-\mylenA-8\tabcolsep\relax}

% calculations
\RequirePackage{calculator}
\newcommand{\resetinvoicesum}{\ADD{0}{0}{\invoicesum}}
\newcommand{\addtoinvoicesum}[1]{\ADD{\invoicesum}{#1}{\invoicesum}\GLOBALCOPY{\invoicesum}{\invoicesum}}

% invoice environment
\newenvironment{invoice}{%
    \resetnumberedlist\resetinvoicesum
    \medskip\par\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{}
       l
       >{\raggedright}p{\invoicedescwidth}
       S[table-format=5.1]
       S[table-format=5.4]
       r @{}}%
       \toprule[0.7pt]
       \textbf{Pos.} & 
       \textbf{Beschreibung} & 
       {\textbf{Anzahl}} & 
       {\textbf{Einzelpreis}} & 
       \textbf{Gesamtpreis} \\ 
       \midrule[0.7pt]}{%
       \bottomrule[0.7pt] 
       \addlinespace
       \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{%
         \textbf{Rechnungsbetrag}\hspace{0.75em}% 
         \textbf{\EUR{\invoicesum}}} \\ 
       \addlinespace
       \end{tabular}
     \par
}

\newcommand{\invoiceitem}[3]{
    \numberedlistitem & 
    #1 & #2 & 
    \EURsimple{#3} & 
    \MULTIPLY{#2}{#3}{\tempsum} 
    \ROUND[2]{\tempsum}{\tempsum} 
    \addtoinvoicesum{\tempsum} 
    \EUR{\tempsum}\\} 


\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{recipient}
    \opening{Hello}
    \Blindtext[1]
        
    \begin{invoice}
        \invoiceitem{Arbeitszeit in h}{800}{15}
        \invoiceitem{Schrauben}{2134}{0.1}
        \invoiceitem{Strommenge in kWh}{303.5}{0.3175}
        \invoiceitem{Position C}{2}{1123.1}
          
    \end{invoice}   
    \end{letter}
    
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address one of the OP's follow-up comments: If you use a non-default sans-serif font -- especially one that uses variable-width digits -- I suggest you delay calculating the length parameters `\mylenA` and `\invoicedescwidth` until after `\begin{document}` and change the code block to

```
\newlength\mylenA
\newlength\invoicedescwidth
\settowidth\mylenA{%   
  \textsf{\textbf{Pos.Gesamtpreis}%
     \num[group-separator={\,}]{22222,2}%
     \num[group-separator={.}]{22222,2222}}}
\setlength\invoicedescwidth{%
  \dimexpr\textwidth-\mylenA-8\tabcolsep\relax}
```

Comment: What does casting in `\textsf` do? And why did you choose the numbers: `22\,124,511.123,3175`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and re-formatting the tabular by making the Rechnungsbetrag span more columns to make the tabular look more aestetically pleasing. I had implemented something similar but I really like the line under the end sum therefore I had removed that implementation. Is there a way to keep it?

Comment: @mrCarnivore - `\textsf` ("text sans serife") is needed since you want to render the table in a sans-serife font (cf `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}`). The numbers `22\,124,5` (incl. `\,` thinspace) and `11.123,3175` are the widest possible entries in columns 3 and 4. Speaking for myself, I find that underlining something as a means of emphasis tends to look vulgar -- I'd avoid it. Using **bold-facing** provides more than enough (maybe even too much?) emphasis as it is.

Comment: Thanks. I guessed in that direction but was confused by the `,` and `.` which I had interpreted as english punctuation marks and therefore there were 3 numbers that did not match my expectation. Your solution breaks (line is way too long) when using `\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{inter}` as a font instead. Strange...

Comment: @mrCarnivore - If you absolutely must resort to underlining, I suggest you run `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} \renewcommand\ULthickness{0.7pt} \setlength\ULdepth{5pt}` in the preamble and execute `\uline{\textbf{Rechnungsbetrag}\hspace{0.75em}\textbf{\EUR{\invoicesum}}}}` in the `invoice` environment.

Comment: If you use a non-default sans-serif font, I suggest you delay the width calculations (of `\mylenA` and `\invoicedescwidth` until after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Good idea. I added a `\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{` around the calculations but there is no difference...

Comment: @mrCarnivore - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Answer (score 5):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` provides the ability to use `X` columns similar to those of `tabularx`. Unlike `tabularx`, `nicematrix` does not compile several times the tabular within a scratch box during a run of LaTeX but writes information on the `aux` file (and requires several runs of LaTeX).

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\RequirePackage{xspace}

% =====================================
% correct number displaying

\usepackage[mode=text, reset-text-series = false, separate-uncertainty, group-digits=integer, group-minimum-digits = 4]{siunitx}

\sisetup{group-separator = {\,}, input-decimal-markers={,.}, output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\newcommand{\EURsimple}[1]{
    \sisetup{minimum-decimal-digits=2, group-separator = {.}, output-decimal-marker = {,}}
    #1
    \sisetup{minimum-decimal-digits=0, group-separator = {\,}, output-decimal-marker = {,}} 
}

\newcommand{\EUR}[1]{
    \num[minimum-decimal-digits=2, group-separator = {.}, output-decimal-marker = {,}]{#1}\,€
}

% =====================================
% automatic item numbering

\newcommand{\startnumberedlist}{\newcounter{numberedlistcounter}}
\newcommand{\numberedlistitem}{\stepcounter{numberedlistcounter}\thenumberedlistcounter}

% =====================================
% calculation

\RequirePackage{calculator}

\newcommand{\resetinvoicesum}{\ADD{0}{0}{\invoicesum}}
\newcommand{\addtoinvoicesum}[1]{\ADD{\invoicesum}{#1}{\invoicesum}\GLOBALCOPY{\invoicesum}{\invoicesum}}


% =====================================
% invoice environment

\RequirePackage{booktabs}

\newenvironment{invoice}[1][]{\startnumberedlist\resetinvoicesum\par\noindent
    \centering\begin{NiceTabular}{rX[l]S[table-format=5.1]S[table-format=5.4]r}%
        \toprule[0.7pt]\textbf{Pos.} & \textbf{Beschreibung} & \textbf{Anzahl} & \textbf{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Gesamtpreis} \\ \toprule[0.7pt]}
    {\midrule[0.7pt] 
        &&& \textbf{Rechnungsbetrag} & \textbf{\EUR{\invoicesum}}\\ \cmidrule[0.7pt]{4-5} \end{NiceTabular}%
}

% invoiceitem, #1: description, #2: count, #3: price per item
\newcommand{\invoiceitem}[3]{
    \numberedlistitem & #1 & #2 & \EURsimple{#3} & \MULTIPLY{#2}{#3}{\tempsum} \ROUND[2]{\tempsum}{\tempsum} \addtoinvoicesum{\tempsum} \EUR{\tempsum}\\} % price calculation and sum up all prices


\usepackage{Blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{recipient}
        \opening{Hello}
        
        \Blindtext[1]
        
        \begin{invoice}
            \invoiceitem{Arbeitszeit in h}{800}{15}
            \invoiceitem{Schrauben}{2134}{0.1}
            \invoiceitem{Strommenge in kWh and some other long text}{303.5}{0.3175}
            \invoiceitem{Position C}{2}{1123.1}
        \end{invoice}
        
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (several tools, such as `latexmk` will do for you those compilations).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Wow. Thank you! I did not know about `nicematrix`. That is a pretty simple solution. The only thing is: Why it the end result not aligned to the right (the same happened in my example and I cannot explain it)?

Comment: To avoid the extra space, you should not put space before the last double-backslash of en of row. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I had not noticed that that might be causing it.