# Tabular, how to add up values of two cells automatically

Tags: tables, collcell

I am wondering if there is any way that for each row of my table, latex calculates the sum of the two cells and writes it in the new cell.

With the code below, I can automatically sum up the values of two columns but I need to for the first row, have the sum of 375 and 182 to be written in the next cell which is now a ?.

Thank you

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
%% Ignore as many rows I need %%%%
\newtoggle{inTableHeader}% Track if still in header of table
\toggletrue{inTableHeader}% Set initial value
\newcommand*{\StartTableHeader}{\global\toggletrue{inTableHeader}}
\newcommand*{\EndTableHeader}{\global\togglefalse{inTableHeader}}

% Redefine tabular to initialize \StartTableHeader at start and end
\let\OldTabular\tabular%
\let\OldEndTabular\endtabular%
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\StartTableHeader\OldTabular}{\OldEndTabular\StartTableHeader}%
% define new columns for tabular
\newcounter{SumMain}
\newcommand*{\Smacro}[1]{\iftoggle{inTableHeader}{#1}{#1\addtocounter{SumMain}{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\Smacro}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcounter{SumInfo}
\newcommand*{\Smacr}[1]{\iftoggle{inTableHeader}{#1}{#1\addtocounter{SumInfo}{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{I}{>{\collectcell\Smacr}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}

\usepackage[textheight=26cm, textwidth=18cm,headheight=0cm, marginparsep=0cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{spreadtab} % for authomatic sum


\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l||M|I|l||l| }
    \hline  & & Main & Info box & Total & Year   \EndTableHeader \\
        \hline\hline
        1 & Preface & 375 & 182 & ? & 1946  \\ \hline
        2 & Investigation & 906 & 950 & ? & 1920  \\ \hline
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Total} & \theSumMain & \theSumInfo  & -  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See packages `spreadtab` (an example you can see in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604087/) or recent version of the `tabularray` (library `5.5 Library functional`).

Comment: Thank you. The problem is spreadtab isn't consistent with newcolumntype

Comment: Really? What special column type than you use? Consider answer in the provided link. Package `tabularray` has high customable column types which can easy fulfil your demands (to my opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got the infrastructure in place.  Just add a little bit of additional code using a new counter `SumRow`.  Just define it with the contents of `Main` and augment it with the contents of `Info Box`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
%% Ignore as many rows I need %%%%
\newtoggle{inTableHeader}% Track if still in header of table
\toggletrue{inTableHeader}% Set initial value
\newcommand*{\StartTableHeader}{\global\toggletrue{inTableHeader}}
\newcommand*{\EndTableHeader}{\global\togglefalse{inTableHeader}}

% Redefine tabular to initialize \StartTableHeader at start and end
\let\OldTabular\tabular%
\let\OldEndTabular\endtabular%
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\StartTableHeader\OldTabular}{\OldEndTabular\StartTableHeader}%
% define new columns for tabular
\newcounter{SumRow}
\newcounter{SumMain}
\newcommand*{\Smacro}[1]{\iftoggle{inTableHeader}{#1}{#1\addtocounter{SumMain}{#1}%
  \setcounter{SumRow}{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\Smacro}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcounter{SumInfo}
\newcommand*{\Smacr}[1]{\iftoggle{inTableHeader}{#1}{#1\addtocounter{SumInfo}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{SumRow}{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{I}{>{\collectcell\Smacr}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}

\usepackage[textheight=26cm, textwidth=18cm,headheight=0cm, marginparsep=0cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{spreadtab} % for authomatic sum


\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l||M|I|l||l| }
    \hline  & & Main & Info box & Total & Year   \EndTableHeader \\
        \hline\hline
        1 & Preface & 375 & 182 & \theSumRow & 1946  \\ \hline
        2 & Investigation & 906 & 950 & \theSumRow & 1920  \\ \hline
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Total} & \theSumMain & \theSumInfo  & - &\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]